# border-style:dashed is being displayed wrongly when using firefox

Tags: css

i have define the following insdie my .css file to display a dash line in my footer:-

```
.dash{
border-style:dashed ;
border-width:2px;
border-color:#322f32;
}
```

then on the footer i have addedd the folloiwng:-

```
<hr/ class="dash">
```

The dash line will be displayed well on internet explorer but it will not be displayed well on firefox ,, so what is the reason behind this ,,, and is it safer to have this dashed line as an image inside?
BR

Comment: What does the result look like? What happens if you use a different element, eg. a `<div>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps your are trying to achieve something like:

[image]

See this [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/uNPLs/)!

**CSS**

```
.dash{
  border: 0 none;
  border-top: 2px dashed #322f32;
  background: none;
  height:0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<hr class="dash" />
```

To have it equal on all browsers.

The `<hr />` comes with some default values depending on the browser, and to an equal presentation on all browsers, you need to reset those values.

Answer (score 1):

Repalce:

```
<hr/ class="dash">
```

With:

```
<hr class="dash" />
```

Comment: Probably not the issue though, hard to tell from the OP's description

Comment: @Pekka: His CSS looks ok unless there is some conflicting style or `!important` somewhere. That's the only thing left to see if everything else is fine.

Comment: I don't have FF here to test, but I'm pretty sure it will just ignore the slash. I think this is to do with the `hr` element and different ways to render it

Comment: @Pekka: Yep that makes the sense too.